# From the distribution of $(X,Y)$ to the distribution of $(X, X-Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the random vector $(X,Y)$. $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Let $H$ be the CDF of $(X,X-Y)$.

Let $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a way to express $H(a,b)$ as a **linear** function of $F$?

By looking at the convolution formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions), it seems I can't, but I would like a confirmation of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: for any pair of real-valued functions $X,Y$ the map $(X,Y)\mapsto (X,X-Y)$ is linear, say $T(X,Y):=(X,X-Y)$. If you set $Z:=(X,Y)$ you have that for any Borel set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$

$$
(TZ)^{-1}(A)=Z^{-1}\circ T^{-1}(A)
$$

Then $\Pr _{TZ}[A]=\Pr [Z^{-1}(T^{-1}A)]=\Pr _Z[T^{-1}A]$, where $\Pr _{TZ}$ is the probability measure defined by $H=F_{TZ}$, and $\Pr _Z$ the measure induced by $F_Z$. Now you can check if, in general, $F_{TZ}=kF_Z$ for some constant $k$ or not.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm confused by the math notation, sorry. Could you write what is for instance $H(2,3)$ as a function of $F$ using your general derivation? In my question, $H$ is the cdf of $X,X-Y$ and $F$ is the cdf of $X,Y$. Just to have a concrete example in mind.

Comment: for your example you will have $H(2,3)=\Pr_{TZ}[(-\infty ,2]\times (-\infty ,3]]=\Pr _Z[T^{-1}((-\infty ,2]\times (-\infty ,3])]$, so you need to find the image of $(-\infty ,2]\times (-\infty ,3]$ under $T^{-1}$. To get an idea you can draw $T^{-1}((-\infty ,2]\times (-\infty ,3])$ in the plane

Comment: $T^{-1}(A)$ is not a rectangle. Hence, $F_{TZ}$ cannot be written as $kF_Z$ in general. Is this the correct way of using your hint?

Comment: @TEX yes, we have that $T^{-1}((-\infty ,2]\times (-\infty ,3])$ is not a set of the form $(-\infty ,s]\times (-\infty ,t]$, so its not possible that $F_{TZ}=K F_{Z}$ for some $k$